# How can I convert a date format to another date format in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I currently have a code:

```
let now = NSDate()
let result: NSDate
result = Cal.iso8601.dateByAddingUnit(.Year, value: -5, toDate: now, options: [])!
return Cal.iso8601.startOfDayForDate(result)
```

that generates a date in the format:

```
2016-09-15 22:00:00 +0000
```

and I want to convert it to this date format:

```
2016-09-16T13:49:23.221Z
```

how can I do it in Swift?

Comment: Use `NSDateFormatter`. There are countless examples of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DateFormatter requires a lot of resources so use this extension so that you only create one instance of the formatter.

```
struct Formatter {
    static let instance = NSDateFormatter(dateFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
}
extension NSDateFormatter {
    convenience init(dateFormat: String) {
        self.init()
        self.dateFormat = dateFormat
    }
}
```

Then just call it with:

```
// dateTime = the date that you want to format
let date = Formatter.instance.dateFromString(dateTime)
```

Comment: That's not the proper date format for the question.

Comment: Your format was correct before the latest update. Now it's wrong again.

Answer (score 0):

```
class func convertDateFormatFromOneFormatToOther(date: String,currentFormat: String,reqFormat : String) -> String
{
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = currentFormat
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: date)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = reqFormat
    return  dateFormatter.string(from: date!)

}
```

> you can use the above method to convert any type of date from one format to another format.

```
Usage: convertDateFormatFromOneFormatToOther(date: "04/03/2021 05:42:19 PM",currentFormat: "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss a",reqFormat : "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss a")
```